# how to send data in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization" : "Token d3f237ec2fab24f874678029b15edfa746003111"
        ]

        let parameters: [String:Any] = [
            "firstname":fristName ,
            "lastname" :lastName ,
            "homeemail" : mail ,
            "prorole" : [

                "pro" : GymID,
                "user" :"",
                "role" : 9
            ],

            "phone_details_user" : [

                "phoneType" : 1 ,
                "phoneNumer" : mobile
            ],
            ]
```

i send data as

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let JSON):

                    successCallback((), JSON as Any as AnyObject)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }
```

it give error
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from a server isn't valid json try using `responseString`, `responseData` or `response` to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Can you explain a bit

Comment: I am getting the same error, pls help me, the same thing working fine in Android side

Comment: Debug how the JSON looks, test it with some kind of Json validator and check where's the problem.